# (Beginner) Inset weight "extruding" faces individually

Tags: modeling, faces, extrude

Pardon the terminology in the title, just to be clear I don't want to extrude at all, but I have an inset I want to do following along with a tutorial where I have the back of an engine I'm modeling and I want to inset the faces a specific way.

With the weight its "extruding" the face individually (first picture) where I want the connected faces to "extrude" together as two connected faces, second picture.

I can't figure it out at all. Please help :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: it looks like a classic extrude

Comment: But not even the extrude works the way I need it too, it always does the same thing whether its Region, Vertex Normals or Individual Faces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand.  First, I don't see any completed inset faces, only the state after extrusion (first that appears to be individual faces, the second that appears to be regions.)  Second, I'm not familiar with your use of the term "weight"; I'm used to it being used to talk about the extent to which a vertex belongs to a particular vertex group.

Note that it would be easy to get the first picture on accident if you have any doubled geometry, possibly by canceled extrusions.  First w->remove doubles.  Also note that extruding one checkered ring, and then extruding the second checkered ring, will get you the first picture, but extruding both together will get you the second.

Now, here's a default (region) extrusion similar to yours:

[image]

If I follow that up with inset faces, I'll get:

[image]

Now, maybe what you're talking about is using an inset follow by a scale; this is basically the same thing as an extrusion anyways.  Here's what happens if I inset with everything selected:

[image]

I can then move those faces any which way I'd like.  However, if I try to do this in two passes, or if I enable "individual" on the operator panel, I get

[image]

You'll notice that if I now try to move those faces, I'll end up with separate faces, as in your first pic.

Comment: I'm sorry with "weight" I meant "depth" in the inset settings

Comment: Don't know why that word popped in my head. After some more investigation I can just extrude it, but in the class I'm doing he insets it and I want a clear understanding of whats going on so I know how to do things in the future. That's all.

Comment: Okay, I've never played with depth so I didn't realize that.  Played just now though.  All of the same stuff applies when using depth.  The fact that you got the first pic is probably due to doubled geometry.  Does it make sense now?